# how do i float these elements

Tags: html, css

I am trying to float my four links so that it is lineal and one next to the other. I am fairly new to CSS, so please bear with me. I have endlessly tried different positions properties and yet can not achieve what I want. Thanks

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
   <head>
  <style>
    body{
         margin:  1px;
         background:green;
        }
 . topbar
      {
         background:url(topbar.gif);
         position:absolute;
         top: 5px;
         right: 15px;
         margin: 2px;
         width: 1200px;
         height: 100px;

       }

 .navbar
       {
        position:absolute;
        float:right;
        width:1200px;
        height:100px;
        border-style:groove;
        }


 a:link {text-decoration:none;color:yellow;}
 a:hover{color:red;}
#titlename
        {
        position:relative;top:10px;
        text-align:center;

        }

</style>
  </head>
    <body>

       <div class="topbar">
       </div>

         <div id="titlename">
         </div>

    <img src="title.gif" alt="title">
    </div>

     <div class="navbar">
      <div class="button"><a href="#" target="_blank">HOME</a>
      <div class="button"><a href="#" target="_blank">ABOUT</a>
      <div class="button"><a href="#" target="_blank">LINKS</a>
      <div class="button"><a href="#" target="_blank">CONTACT</a>
     </div>

   </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: didnt understand you want to float them where i am one here one Thr ???

Comment: I am trying to float the links in div class 'navbar' to the right so that they are all in the same line instead of one under the other. hope that helps.

Comment: BTW- Your CSS is really messy. I have answered your question. Let me know if you get it.

Comment: yes got it. Now I have to figure out why all links are one on top of the other. What do you mean messy? why? Thanks

Comment: Messy means, you can reduce the code. There's unnecessary stuff

Comment: right. thanks. is the actual html structure Okish?

Answer (score 1):

There are various methods to inline the elements.

```
1. using Flex Method
2. using table method
3. using float method
4. using display method.
```

Here you can check the ***[Demo link](http://jsbin.com/jobogulo/10/)***. includes all possibility.

Comment: You copied the code of the question with broken HTML. It works by pure accident. <div> needs to be closed!!

Comment: @user3452524 If the solution work for you; then you can close this question by accepting the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you've noticed since posting your question, but each of your button DIVs is missing it's closing DIV tag. This means that any CSS applied will not have the expected effect. Once you've fixed the HTML, you can use the following CSS to have each navigation item on the same line, spaced out equally, with the menu occupying the full width:

```
.button {
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
}
```

If you don't want the menu to occupy the full width, use padding or margin instead of specifying 25% for the width attribute, e.g:

```
.button {
    float: left;
    padding: 0 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use either use `float: left;` or `display: inline` to achieve what you want.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/yC9Bj/)**

Just add following style to your anchor tags:

```
.navbar a { 
    float:left; 
    margin-right: 15px;
}
```

Comment: thanks that helped. Now I have the four links one on top of the other. How do i space them out?

Comment: You can use margin to space them out.

Comment: You mean, you just want to move one link

Comment: i want to space out all four links on one line

Comment: Can you share a image/design how you want them to look exactly? Only then, I can help.

Comment: HOME            GALLERY                LINKS                  CONTACT

Comment: The above is what I want

Comment: Using inline-block instead of just inline should allow you to space things out with padding and margin.

Comment: Look at the Demo on my answer http://jsfiddle.net/yC9Bj/ That's exactly what I have done. And it's done with margin.

Answer (score 0):

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qCe29/1)

```
.button{
display:inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Add more info about your answer please.

Comment: You should explain what have you done. I'm not the one who asked the question. I was reviewing your answer and I recommended you to add explanation about the fiddle and the code to prevent it from deleting.

Comment: You posted in Fiddle a copy of the broken HTML from the original question? An open tag DIVs needs a closing tag DIV